# Calling a role in another directory for molecule prepare step

Tags: testing, ansible, molecule

I have role, role-1, I am trying to create molecule tests for, but this role is dependent on another role, role-2, located in a different directory.
As part of the molecule setup of the docker container to run the tests in I have a prepare.yml file that I am trying to use to run role-2 so that the container is prepared to run role-1.
Initially I had both this roles in the same location, and didn't have this issue as they were located in the same directory. But I needed to separate the code for the roles for versioning, and I'm running into problems locating role-2 for the testing. This separation is just for development and testing, the roles get installed together in the one location for deployment, so no issue there.

I've tried `import_role`, `include_role`, `roles` in my `prepare.yml` file tasks and updated the `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH:` in the `molecule.yml` file to point to the directory with role-2 and get the same error:

`ERROR! the role 'role-2' was not found in ...`

It lists a bunch of directories including the one set by the ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH value, and points to the line in my `prepare.yml` file with the task `name: role-2`. I had thought it may have been a permissions issues, but using `import_role` I could use the `become: yes` and `become_user: correct_user`to but get the same error.

My prepare.yml file looks like this

```
- name: Prepare
  hosts: all
  vars:
    pkg_list:
      - package-1
      - package-2

  tasks:
    - name: Install packages
      become: yes
      package:
        name: "{{ pkg_list }}"
        state: present

    - name: Install role-2
      become: yes
      become_user: correct-user
      import_role:
        name: role-2
```

Is it possible to do what I need and call a role from another location? Or is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get error - `ERROR! the role 'role-2' was not found in` look at dirs in error. You see dir with your role?
I think you should try this

```
import_role:
        name: role/role-2
```

Comment: That actually works, that's very much.